# Executing a SELECT query causing MySQL server to shut down

Tags: mysql, windows

From a .net MVC web application when user is executing a straight forward sql select query causing the mysql server itself down

The SELECT statement is like this

```
SELECT  ID,  Headline,  Intro_Plaintext, CategoryList, PublishedDate,
MATCH( Headline,  Standfirst_Plaintext,  Intro_Plaintext,  Storytext_PlainText, CategoryList)
    AGAINST('kyeword 2022' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) Score, Brand_ID, Type_Name
FROM index_articles WHERE MATCH(Headline, Standfirst_Plaintext, Intro_Plaintext, Storytext_PlainText, CategoryList)
    AGAINST('kyeword 2022' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND NOT ISNULL(Brand_ID)
```

The table is large is size [ around 1 million records exists and list is growing day by day] .

The create Table script looks like this

```
    CREATE TABLE `index_articles` (
      `index_articles_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Brand_ID` int DEFAULT '0',
      `ID` int DEFAULT '0',
      `Headline` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
      `Standfirst_Plaintext` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
      `Intro_Plaintext` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
      `Storytext_PlainText` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
      `CategoryList` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
      `Type_Name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `PublishedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `UNIXPubDate` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`index_articles_id`) USING BTREE,
      UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`index_articles_id`) USING BTREE,
      UNIQUE KEY `DUPLICATE` (`Brand_ID`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
      KEY `PublishedDateDESC` (`UNIXPubDate` DESC) USING BTREE,
      FULLTEXT KEY `FullTextSearch` (`Headline`,`Standfirst_Plaintext`,`Intro_Plaintext`,`Storytext_PlainText`,`CategoryList`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=237353 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The detailed error log looks like below

```
 [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fts0que.cc:3270:ret == 0 thread 9740
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
09:49:38 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1c59ae139c0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7d0827402    mysqld.exe!?my_errno@@YAHXZ()
7ffb9f7dcfa7    ucrtbase.dll!raise()
7ffb9f7dde31    ucrtbase.dll!abort()
7ff7d0a3fd80    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7d0a8dd04    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7d0a903cc    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7d0a8d38f    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7d08f5e24    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7cfa4c1f9    mysqld.exe!?init_search@Item_func_match@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cfb0967b    mysqld.exe!?init_ftfuncs@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAVSELECT_LEX@@@Z()
7ff7cfbd177a    mysqld.exe!?optimize@JOIN@@QEAA_NXZ()
7ff7cfc1910e    mysqld.exe!?optimize@SELECT_LEX@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cfc9abff    mysqld.exe!?optimize@SELECT_LEX_UNIT@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE@@@Z()
7ff7cfc16218    mysqld.exe!?execute_inner@Sql_cmd_dml@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cfc16016    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cfb1d36d    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7cfb1dfc9    mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVParser_state@@@Z()
7ff7cfb16eb2    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff7cfb17e6e    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7cf9626c8    mysqld.exe!?modify_thread_cache_size@Per_thread_connection_handler@@SAXK@Z()
7ff7d0c222a1    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7d082739c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_join@@YAHPEAUmy_thread_handle@@PEAPEAX@Z()
7ffb9f78fb80    ucrtbase.dll!_o__realloc_base()
7ffba24c84d4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffba2a11791    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1c5a391f238): SELECT  ID,  Headline,  Intro_Plaintext, CategoryList, PublishedDate,
MATCH( Headline,  Standfirst_Plaintext,  Intro_Plaintext,  Storytext_PlainText, CategoryList)
    AGAINST('kyeword 2022' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) Score, Brand_ID, Type_Name
FROM index_articles WHERE MATCH(Headline, Standfirst_Plaintext, Intro_Plaintext, Storytext_PlainText, CategoryList)
    AGAINST('kyeword 2022' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND NOT ISNULL(Brand_ID)
Connection ID (thread ID): 12019
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Any idea what is causing this issue? Is it some Mysql server configuration issues? Also this is not frequent Occasionally only this problem is occurring

Comment: Try running the query with `explain` might help you to understand the query performance

Comment: Running query directly in server from Heidi/ Mysql front is not causing any troubles. From the website on form submission when this query is getting executed problems occurring . Again this will work without any issues most of the times

Comment: A wild guess - Are you inserting the records in this table also? If yes then the problem could be you have multiple index which need to be rebuild which might be taking time when you are querying the record.

Comment: Inserts are happening via some different threads / from different side of the application . The select query is a part of global search  functionality and when someone search for a term from the website this select query is getting executed and occasionally this is causing server to down . Not sure is it something wrong with query or with Mysql server config or with some cache settings etc

Comment: In my understanding you need to look at your data points - try to isolate the problem, and try to understand the pattern when this is happening. 

- The number of records in the table using the explain on your production environment  - try replicating the same in local for testing 

- Look for time when the query is breaking and check which all queries getting executed at that time. be careful while enabling global query log on prod env. 

- Your problem statement is very broad right now, you need to isolate it before solving.

Comment: This is a bug within MySql itself, there are some diagnostic tips here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/crashing.html as well as a link to report a bug.  There are compression calls in the stack dump, if the target table has compression enabled perhaps try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: Try changing `NOT ISNULL(Brand_ID)` to `Brand_ID IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE index_articles`.  And try `CHECK TABLE index_articles;`

Comment: @RickJames The Create TABLE is added to the question and Check Index showing OK status on server Op[Check] Msg_Type[status] Msg_Text [OK]

Comment: @RickJames No difference even after changing the logic from NOT ISNULL(Brand_ID) to Brand_ID IS NOT NULL. Even tried to run as Brnad_id >=0

Comment: @Sebastian - `>=0` is false for NULL.  So, assuming you have no negative values, you get the same answer.  However, since it is a "range" instead of effectively an "=", it is not as easily optimized.

Comment: @Sebastian  - "fts0que" smells like a FULLTEXT routine.  Suggest you file a bug with bugs.mysql.com ,  I don't think I have ever seen 4 LONGTEXTs in a single FT index.  (But  I would expect it to be OK.)

Comment: @RickJames FULLTEXT is the culprit and unfortunately we have to rely on FullText search. But managed to sort out this issue. Applying  server side pagination will resolve the issue in the end The actual select returns almost 15k rows and fetching 5/6 full text columns as a part of SELECT statement was causing this issue. Instead of getting 15k records, now i am planning to do a proper serverside pagination by LIMIT results to page size and the issue is resolved

Comment: @Sebastian - Please file a bug report.  (And provide a link to it here.)